# Display variable and array

Tags: javascript, react-native

Guys I have a question.

I have an app in which I register data from an external device using BLE.

I have a "time" and an array for "acceleration".

```
const time = parseInt(
          Buffer.from(characteristic.value, "base64")
            .readUInt16LE(0)
            .toString(16),
          16
        );
        const acc_dx = [2, 4, 6].map(index => {
          const hex = Buffer.from(characteristic.value, "base64")
            .readInt16LE(index)
            .toString(16);
          return Number.parseInt(hex, 16);
        });
        const accUpdate_acc_dx = [...this.state.array_acc_dx, this.state.time, this.state.acc_dx]
        this.setState({ array_acc_dx: accUpdate_acc_dx })
```

the result for **array_acc_dx** is like:

> [1520,[42,-419,-926],1520,[41,-420,-927],1520,[41,-421,-927],1520,[41,-421,-926],1580,[40,-420,-927],1640,[40,-420,-926],1640,[41,-420,-926],1640,[41,-419,-926]

I would obtain this:

> 1520: [42,-419,-926],
>
> 1520: [41,-420,-927],
>
> 1520: [41,-421,-927],
>
> 1580: [40,-420,-927],

How can I do to have this kind of array?

Comment: off topic: what's the point of `parseInt( someNumber.toString(16), 16);`?

Comment: @Thomas it is to convert a number to string

Comment: @Jack23 but `someNumber.toString(16)` will return the number in hex as a string...then doing `parseInt(str, 16)` will convert that hex value into a number again. If `readUInt16LE` returns a number, then you don't need the double conversion to get the same number. And if it doesn't, I don't think a double conversion is needed.

Comment: @VLAZ Now I'm trying what you said :)

Comment: [according to the docs](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_buf_readint16le_offset), `readInt16LE` returns an integer which is linked to [MDN Number type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Data_structures#Number_type).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've cleaned up a few bits in your code, but I assume the following code does what you want it to do.

- I don't think it is necessary to use a seperate buffer for each index you want to read.
- I've already mentioned the part about converting a number to hex, just to immediately parse it back to a number; that's useless code.
- you can parse the values for `time` and `acc_dx` in one go. No need to duplicate code.
- when updating the state based on a previous state, use `this.setState(previousState => newState)`

```
const buf = Buffer.from(characteristic.value, "base64");
const [time, ...acc_dx] = [0,2,4,6].map(index => buf.readInt16LE(index));

this.setState(state => ({
  time,
  acc_dx,
  array_acc_dx: [
    ...state.array_acc_dx, 
    [time, acc_dx]
  ]
}));
```

Comment: Can you give me an hand about a part of this code? Thank you

Comment: @Jack23 sure, what's the problem/question?

Comment: I have a similar problem with another variable: 
const [time, ...pressure ] = [0, 2, 4, 6, 8].map(index => buf.readUInt16LE(index));
But the problem is that pressure accept data like: P1 (2 bytes), P2 (2 bytes), P3 (2 bytes), P4 (2 bytes), P5 (2 bytes). So I can't insert the time. Do you know how can I do?

Comment: @Jack23 is the time in that case no int16LE, like in this question? Then parse `time` and `pressure` seperately. I've combined `time` and `acc_dx` because they were **all** computed as `buf.readInt16LE(index)`

Comment: So can I use the time like in my post? And then how can I combine it with the pressure?